# Getting a hyperlink inside an excel file that directs to a specific page in a PDF

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to have multiple links in a column of an excel file which when clicked open a pdf to a specific page.

According to this: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

What I've tried :

```
# doc_path : path/to/file.pdf
pages_to_get = [1, 5, 88, 157]
# bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path='abc.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
main_df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name='main')
main_sheet = writer.sheets['main']
doc_prefix = 'file://'
# doc_prefix = 'internal:file://'

for p in range(len(pages_to_get)):
    page_url = str(doc_prefix+ doc_path + '#page=' + str(pages_to_get[p]))
    print(page_url)
    main_sheet.write_url(col=2, row=(p + 1), url=page_url, string='Go To Page'+str(pages_to_get[p]))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

But the issue is that the hyperlinks in the excel file only open the pdf to the first page.

Comment: Does the link to the page work outside of Excel?  In a simple html file for example.

Comment: Well if you simply add '#page=x' after any local pdf url opened in a browser, it opens up that page. But when stored as a hyperlink in an excel,it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. Does the url work if you add it directly to a cell in Excel, without involving pandas or xlsxwriter

Comment: nope. if you manually create a hyperlink out of it, it still goes to the first page of the file. However if you copypaste the link on a browser,it works as intended

Comment: In that case it looks like the link rendering engine in Excel doesn't support this syntax. All the solutions suggested by Google seem to require using VBA to call Internet Explorer as an object to render the link. So, if you can't get Excel to follow the link correctly then you aren't going to be able to do it with xlsxwriter (unless you come up with some general VBA solution and then [embed that macro into an xlsxwriter file](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html)).

Comment: yep. came to the same conclusion. strange why it is not possible cause it seems like a trivial thing. Anyways I suppose the best way is to convert pdf into something else first, like html. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is NO way to do this directly with a pdf
However you may convert the pdf to some other format (like HTML)